# SSH connects successfully then disconnects when typing any key

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, openssh

When I connect from my laptop I am able to connect successfully and if I do not type anything the connection stays open. However, any keystroke results in the connection being broken with the message `qpacket_write_wait: Connection to {ip} port 22: Broken pipe`

When I search for this error, all of the results deal with inactivity. In my case, it is not inactivity, but any keystroke sent to the server.

I am able to connect and issue commands from other computers on the network. I have tested using Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop as well as Win 10 through the Ubuntu bash terminal. The only difference between the other machines and my laptop is that they are hardwired while the laptop is wireless.

Here is the output from the connection and keystroke when using `ssh -vvv`

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "{server}" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to {server} [192.168.1.121] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/{user}/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/{user}/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/{user}/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/{user}/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/{user}/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/{user}/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/{user}/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/{user}/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to {server}:22 as '{user}'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/{user}/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/{user}/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from {server}
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:{key}
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/{user}/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/{user}/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from {server}
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/{user}/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/{user}/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.121
debug1: Host '{server}' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/{user}/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/{user}/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55aba4d34e40), agent
debug2: key: /home/{user}/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/{user}/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/{user}/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/{user}/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:{key}
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:{key}
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to {server} ([192.168.1.121]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env MANPATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR
debug3: Ignored env CLUTTER_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env SESSION
debug3: Ignored env NVM_CD_FLAGS
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug3: Ignored env UPSTART_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL
debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env NVM_DIR
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env QT_ACCESSIBILITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_PATH
debug3: Ignored env UNITY_HAS_3D_SUPPORT
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT_PATH
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env DEFAULTS_PATH
debug3: Ignored env LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env UNITY_DEFAULT_PROFILE
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env QT_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME
debug3: Ignored env NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env JOB
debug3: Ignored env XMODIFIERS
debug3: Ignored env EDITOR
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_PID
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env GDM_LANG
debug3: Ignored env MANDATORY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE
debug3: Ignored env IM_CONFIG_PHASE
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env SESSIONTYPE
debug3: Ignored env GTK2_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env LANGUAGE
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env UPSTART_INSTANCE
debug3: Ignored env UPSTART_EVENTS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env COMPIZ_BIN_PATH
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env QT4_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env NVM_BIN
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env NVM_IOJS_ORG_MIRROR
debug3: Ignored env INSTANCE
debug3: Ignored env UPSTART_JOB
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GTK_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-128-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

4 packages can be updated.
1 update is a security update.


*** System restart required ***
Last login: Fri Jun 29 13:11:52 2018 from 192.168.1.1
{user}@{server}:~$ fdebug3: send packet: type 1
packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.1.121 port 22: Broken pipe
```

I am at a loss as to why this connection works on other machines but not the laptop. Any assistance or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Because the `{user}@{server}`'s login fails. Check `/etc/sshrc`, `~{user}/.ssh/rc`.

Comment: @waltinator  I don't understand your comment. The {user}@{server}'s login is not failing. As I stated in the question and as you can see in the output, it connects successfully. The issue is that any commands that I try to issue immediately disconnect me. This is not a server issue, as I can connect under the same user from other machines on the same network. It is specific to my laptop. Regardless, I have neither `/etc/sshrc` or `~/.ssh/rc` files on my machine.